# Java Pattern validation annotation and util Regex pattern behave differently

Tags: java, regex, validation

I have a regex

```
^(?=[a-zA-Z0-9,!@#$&*()_'+-=<>.?{}\\[\\]|; :\\s]*$)(?!.*[/])
```

and I tried the regex through two approaches for string `"hello"`:

1. `java.util.regex.Pattern` : would pass the test
2. `javax.validation.constraints.Pattern` (annotation): would throw an error that invalid values are present.

Does anyone have any idea why these two are behaving differently?

Comment: At any rate the `-` inside must be either escaped or placed at the end of the `[...]` character class

Comment: That expression looks a bit odd, e.g. that huge character class in the look-ahead seems to allow almost any ascii character except the forward slash. If your input can be ascii only anyways, wouldn't `[^/]` be easier to read (provided all you want is the input _not_ to start with a slash)?

Comment: @maraca annotations are configured using strings so you'd need to double escape there as well.

Comment: Can you please also post how you test using `java.util.regex.Pattern`? I'm not that familiar with javax.validation but I'd guess that it requires the input to pass `matches()` and if you don't use that in your other tests as well that might be the reason for your difference. You also might want to tell us what your regex should and shouldn't match - I have the strong feeling that it is too complicated (I might be wrong though).

Comment: That can be shorten to: `^[!#$&-.0-\\[\\]_a-}\\s]*$`

Comment: @maraca: note that `+-=` defines a range that includes the slash.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte yes true, but I doubt that it is what he wanted. So it should be this: `^[a-zA-Z0-9,!@#$&*()_'+=<>.?{}\\[\\]|;:\\s-]*$`

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte, you're assuming a lot about the character set and locale being used on the target system with that. Much better to use POSIX character classes and manually specify the other characters. Something like `^[[:alnum:],!@#$&*()_'+=<>.?{}\\[\\]|;:\\s-]*$` could work.

Comment: @Samadi: I assume absolutely nothing, and this has nothing to do with locales since it uses only ascii characters (as in the original pattern), see the ascii table for more informations about the ranges used in my suggested pattern.

Comment: @Samadi: other thing, Java regex doesn't support POSIX character classes.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte, well, non-standard character sets do exist, but yes, it will usually be ASCII or Unicode. I didn't know about Java not supporting POSIX character classes. Thanks for letting me know!

Comment: It would be helpful to know the exact error message and which javax.validation implementation and version you are using. (I assume Hibernate Validator?)

Answer (score 1):

At least for your given test string of `"hello"`, it seems that the two regexs do behave the same, so it's difficult to know what you're running into, without further information.

This short program tests both. Sample output is given underneath.

```
public class RegexTest {

  static final String REGEX = "^(?=[a-zA-Z0-9,!@#$&*()_'+-=<>.?{}\\[\\]|; :\\s]*$)(?!.*[/])";

  static final String TEST = "hello";

  public static class TestObject {
    @javax.validation.constraints.Pattern(regexp=REGEX)
    String name;
  }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
     test1();
     test2();
   }

   public static void test1() {
     java.util.regex.Pattern p = java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(REGEX);
     Matcher m = p.matcher(TEST);
     System.out.println(m.matches()); // false, ie, doesn't match
   }

   public static void test2() {
     TestObject to = new TestObject();
     to.name = TEST;

     ValidatorFactory factory = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory();
     Validator validator = factory.getValidator();
     Set<ConstraintViolation<TestObject>> violations = validator.validate(to);
     for(ConstraintViolation<TestObject> violation : violations) {
       System.out.println(violation.getMessage()); // One violation, "must match"
     }
   }
}
```

---

```
false
INFO  o.h.validator.internal.util.Version - HV000001: Hibernate Validator 5.2.4.Final
must match "^(?=[a-zA-Z0-9,!@#$&*()_'+-=<>.?{}\[\]|; :\s]*$)(?!.*[/])"
```